# Is it possible to add the monitor from the second GPU to the same x screen as the first GPU?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, manjaro, nvidia-settings

Manjaro. Gnome. Nvidia.

I have two GPUs (ASUS 1070 both).

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

Both GPUs and monitors are detected, but I cannot add the second monitor (the smallest, orange on the screenshot) to the X Screen 0. I can only create new X screen 1, but even if I select X Screen 1, I cannot save settings. (second screenshot)

[image: image 2]

> The current settings cannot be completely applied due to one or more of the following reasons:
>
> - The location of an X screen has changed
> - The location type of an X screen has changed
> - The color depth of an X screen has changed
> - An X screen has been added or removed.
> - Xinerama is being enabled/disabled.
>
> For all the requested settings to take effect, you must save the configuration to the X config file and restart the X server.
>
> <kbd>Apply What Is Possible</kbd>  <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

I was trying a lot of things, but nothing seems to help. So, I even have a conclusion that it is not possible. I am not experienced in Xorg, etc. at all, so I think there should be some solution.

My xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 410.57

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "MultiGPU" "on"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "COMPOSITE" "Enable"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard        "yes"
    Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add a monitor from a second GPU to the same X screen as the first GPU

To do this, you need to make sure that both GPUs are recognized by the system and that the necessary drivers are installed. Then, you can use the xrandr command to configure the display settings and add the second monitor to the same X screen as the first GPU.

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Install the necessary drivers for both GPUs. You can check the official documentation of your GPU vendor for instructions.
2. Check if both GPUs are recognized by the system using the lspci command. You should see two GPU entries listed.
3. Use the xrandr command to check the available displays and their connected status. You can use the following command:

```
xrandr --query
```

4. Check the names of the connected displays, which will be used in the next steps.
5. Use xrandr to add the second monitor to the first GPU's X screen. You can use the following command:

```
xrandr --output [name of second monitor] --mode [resolution] --right-of [name of first monitor]
```

Replace the [name of second monitor], [resolution], and [name of first monitor] with the corresponding values from the previous steps.

This command should add the second monitor to the right of the first monitor on the same X screen. You can adjust the position and other settings using xrandr as needed.

Note that some GPUs may require additional configuration or setup, and not all GPUs may be compatible with this setup. Make sure to check the documentation and support forums for your GPU and Linux distribution for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).